# Use SELECT through three table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I tried to write a query, but unfortunately I didn't succeed.
I want to know how many packages delivered over a given period by a person.
So I want to know how many packages were delivered by John (user_id = 1) between 01-02-18 and 28-02-18. John drives another car (another plate_id) every day.
(orders_drivers.user_id, plates.plate_name, orders.delivery_date, orders.package_amount)

I have 3 table:

**orders** with *`plate_id`* *`delivery_date`* *`package_amount`*
**plates** with *`plate_id`* *`plate_name`*
**orders_drivers** with *`plate_id`* *`plate_date`* *`user_id`*

I tried some solutions but didn't get the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: Check out `JOIN`!

Comment: What exactly did you tried?

Comment: I know join, but this query is too complex for me.

Comment: If this query is too complex for you, I have some bad news about your career....

Comment: If this query is too complex for you, you should just find other non database job.  Queries, at least the useful ones, won't get any easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JOINS  as shown below:

```
SELECT SUM(o.package_amount)
FROM orders o INNER JOIN orders_drivers od
ON o.plate_id=od.plate_id
WHERE od.user_id=<the_user_id>;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for insight.

You can also use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(o.package_amount)
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM orders_drivers od
              WHERE user_id=<user_id> AND o.plate_id=od.plate_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(orders.package_amount) AS amount
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN plates ON orders.plate_id = orders_drivers.plate_id
LEFT JOIN orders_driver ON orders.plate_id = orders_drivers.plate_id
WHERE orders.delivery_date > date1 AND orders.delivery_date < date2 AND orders_driver.user_id = userid
GROUP BY orders_drivers.user_id
```

But seriously, you need to ask questions that makes more sense.

sum is a function to add all values that has been grouped by GROUP BY.

LEFT JOIN connects all tables by id = id. Any other join can do this in this case, as all ids are unique (at least I hope).

WHERE, where you give the dates and user.

And GROUP BY userid, so if there are more records of the same id, they are returned as one (and summed by their pack amount.)

With the AS, your result is returned under the name 'amount',

Comment: I can't use orders_driver in where clause, if i don't join to it.

Comment: Yes, fixed... but you need to fix these as we don't know all your informations. I mean, you don't just copy-paste it, but alter for your own code. Here people will show you the door, but you have to find the doorknob yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total of packageamount by user in a period, you can use this query:

**UPDATE**: add a `where` clause on `user_id`, to retrieve John related data

```
 SELECT od.user_id
         , p.plate_name
         , SUM(o.package_amount) AS TotalPackageAmount
    FROM   orders_drivers od
    JOIN   plates p
      ON o.plate_id = od.plate_id
    JOIN   orders o
      ON o.plate_id = od.plate_id
    WHERE  o.delivery_date BETWEEN convert(datetime,01/02/2018,103) AND convert(datetime,28/02/2018,103)
      AND  od.user_id = 1
        GROUP  BY od.user_id
                , p.plate_name
```

It `groups` rows on `user_id` and `plate_name`, filter a period of `delivery_date`(s) and then calculate the sum of packageamount for the group

Comment: There is no error (i swap two join, becouse first join can't reach orders table), but it does not run, just loading.

Comment: Its seems a performance issue, did you check your table structure, are there indexed in `plate_id` column on each tables? An index in `delivery_date` may improve performance in some cases. Lastly you can try to filter on a specific `user_id` or a `plate_id` to minimise the size of the dataset